# set up expiration for putObject in s3 php sdk

Tags: php, amazon-s3, aws-php-sdk

This is working codes for creating bucket and putObject:

```
$bucket = uniqid("php-sdk-sample-", true);
echo "Creating bucket named {$bucket}\n";
$result = $client->createBucket(array(
'Bucket' => $bucket
));
// Wait until the bucket is created
$key = 'hello_world.txt';
echo "Creating a new object with key {$key}\n";
$result = $client->createObject(array(
'Bucket' => $bucket,
'Key'    => $key,
'Body'   => "Hello World!" 
));
```

How can I set up expiration date for this just created object ? For ex. I want to see disappear the uploaded file 3 days later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read and learn about [S3 object lifecycle management](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-lifecycle-mgmt.html) first, then you can use the [`putBucketLifecycle` operation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_putBucketLifecycle) to configure it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. although its not working with sdk 2.6.*, this solved the problem ;
 `create_object_expiration_config ( $bucket, $opt )`
in sdk 1.6.2.

this is [link.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/index.html#m=AmazonS3/create_object_expiration_config)

Comment: I've implemented some files from sdk 1.6.2 and used this method above.